# Why is the value of jDateChooser back to the default value?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jdatechooser

I'm using jDateChooser in NetBeans, and when I run the program and choose any date, it is not choosing correctly.
For example, if I choose 05-05-2020, it shows 29-12-2018.

Also, if it catches the selected date, when I press on another item (any button or text field), the date returns to its default.

I didn't add any code related to it; I only took it from the tools box and put it on the frame.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i am using wrong date format, it was YYYY-MM-dd, the correct one is yyyy- MM-dd